# Restoring the order of TestSuites from a Testlink XML-RPC response?

Tags: java, api, testing, report, xml-rpc

I would like to use the [Testlink API](http://code.google.com/p/testlink-api-java-client/) to retrieve `TestCases`/`TestSuites` and display them in a report. They should be sorted in the same order as they appear in the Testlink 'Test Specification' (a folder-like structure that can be reordered by mouse drag-and-drop).

Each `TestCase` returned by the RPC-XML API consists of a parameter `z` that describes its position within a `TestSuite`. Reconstructing the order of `TestCases` is therefore possible. However, there is no analogous parameter for ordering `TestSuites` within a project. For example, the following two lines can be used to obtain the `TestSuites` from Testlink...

```
conn = new TestLinkAPIClient(testlinkKey, testlinkURL);
TestLinkAPIResults suites = conn.getTestSuitesForTestPlan(testplanID);
```

... but the result only contains information about their hierarchy (`parent_id`), no information about their order is available.

```
Result[0] = {id=6754, name=TestThree, parent_id=6752}
...
Result[8] = {id=22818, name=TestOne, parent_id=6754}
Result[9] = {id=22819, name=TestTwo, parent_id=6754}
```

Is is possible to somehow reconstruct the order from the XML-RPC response so that I can list the `Testcases` exactly as they appear in the 'Test Specification'?

Comment: Maybe you could post a screenshot of the GUI and the contents of the XML-RPC response?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a kind of "cheating way" to get the order :

```
conn = new TestLinkAPIClient(testlinkKey, testlinkURL);
TestLinkAPIResults suites = conn.getTestSuitesForTestPlan(testplanID);
for(int i=0; i<suites.length;i++){
   List<Integer> id = new LinkedList();
   id.add(suites[i].getId());
   System.out.println("order for "+suites[i].getName()+" = "+conn.getTestSuitesById(id)[0].getOrder());
}
```

I personnally used the testlink java api https://jar-download.com/java-documentation-javadoc.php?a=testlink-java-api&g=br.eti.kinoshita&v=1.9.2-1 but I think yours is quite the same.

Hope it will help you